# phpunit monolog console output too verbose

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm running phpunit from within symfony2 and am seeing every log entry output to stdout.

I have removed all monolog handlers and other config entries from all config.yml files so assume it's a default setting of the symfony-phpunit bridge or something.

This is my phpunit.xml.dist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="app/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
    </php>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="\Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\TestListener"
                  file="Mockery/Adapter/Phpunit/TestListener.php">
        </listener>
    </listeners>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Any ideas on removing this output?

ETA, the tests are using an instantiated monolog instance as shown below:

```
 /**
   * @return Logger
   */
  protected function getLogger() {
    $logger = new Logger('test');
    $logger->pushHandler(new DebugHandler);
    return $logger;
  }
```

(removing the debugHandler has no effect).

It's behaviour is akin to there being a handler that outputs to stdout yet this isn't the case. Here are some of the output when i run phpunit:

```
 Matthews-iMac:api matt$ phpunit ./tests/ONC/Test/Partridge/Import/Importer/ImportStaticTest.php
PHPUnit 5.2.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E..[2016-03-31 12:37:27] test.DEBUG: [PARSE]   Could not parse data String could not be parsed as XML <oxip version="7.1" created="2016-02-20 12:05:53" lastMsgId="" requestTime="0.0584"> <response request="getCategories" code="001" message="success" debug="" provider="GENERIC"> <disclaimer></disclaimer> <category id="16" displayOrder="-788" name="Football" category="FOOTBALL"/ <category id="34" displayOrder="-777" name="Tennis" category="TENNIS"/> <category id="23" displayOrder="230" name="Motor Bikes" category="MOTOR_BIKES"/> <category id="36" displayOrder="360" name="Volleyball" category="VOLLEYBALL"/> </responseBROKEN> </oxip>  [] []
.[2016-03-31 12:37:27] test.ERROR: [MAPPING] Could not map parsed response to stdClass | feed: CORAL_OPENBET, domain: ONC\Partridge\Entity\Category1, current key with cast: category, current key without cast: category, current result: array (   'id' => '16',   'displayOrder' => '-788',   'name' => 'Football',   'categoryBELL' => 'FOOTBALL', ), mappings: array (   'name' => 'name',   'category' => 'canonicalised_name',   '(int)displayOrder' => 'display_order', ), Request: http://xmlfeeds.coral.co.uk/oxi/pub?template=getCategories [] []
```

Comment: what kind of log you see on the stdout?

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the stdout to the console in a test case with the `setOutputCallback` method with a dummy callback. As Example:

```
public function testDlRegisteredUserWithoutPointAction()
{
    // Suppress StreamedResponse output to console
    $this->setOutputCallback(function() {});
    ....
}
```

[Here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.output.tables.api) more docs.

Hope this help

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effect. Please see edits to the original question

Answer (score 1):

False alarm, it was a monolog instance of my own making and not symfony-managed one. Duh